# Read more than one input in x86

Tags: assembly, x86

I need to read an input and store it, but input needs to have more than 1 digit, like 45 or 55.

I already made it work, but I think it's possible to make it better. I made it this way:

```
mov     ah, 1
int     21h           
mov     ah, 0
mov     cl, 0Ah
sub     al, 30h ; 
mul     cl
mov     bx, ax
mov     ah, 1
int     21h     
sub     al, 30h ; '0'
add     bx, ax
mov     temp_val, bl
retn
```

Is it possible? I can't do it other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in your code

```
mov     ah, 1
int     21h           
mov     ah, 0   ; <-- Here MOV AH,0 is useless because ...
mov     cl, 0Ah
sub     al, 30h
mul     cl      ; <-- ... MUL changes AH anyway
mov     bx, ax
mov     ah, 1
int     21h     
sub     al, 30h
                ; <-- Here you forgot MOV AH,0 so you can ...
add     bx, ax  ; <-- ... correctly add AX to BX
```

But if all you need is a 2 character input the consider the following

```
mov     ah, 1
int     21h           
mov     cl, 0Ah
sub     al, 30h
mul     cl
mov     bl, al
mov     ah, 1
int     21h     
sub     al, 30h
add     bl, al   ; Largest number is 99 so it fits in BL
```

Or even without using the MUL instruction and shorter

```
mov     ah, 1
int     21h           
mov     bl, al
mov     ah, 1
int     21h     
mov     ah,bl
sub     ax, 3030h
aad
mov     bl, al   ; Largest number is 99 so it fits in BL
```

Comment: Fifoernik, thank you so much! Solved my problem with a good explanation